# NoReverseMatch Exception using mezzanine.mobile

Tags: django, mobile, mezzanine

I'm pretty new to `Mezzanine` and I'm having some difficulty getting the option **View Mobile Site** available in my `index.html`.

**SETUP**

In the `settings.py`, I specified the following:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    "newsletters",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.redirects",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.sitemaps",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "mezzanine.boot",
    "mezzanine.conf",
    "mezzanine.core",
    "mezzanine.generic",
    "mezzanine.pages",
    "mezzanine.blog",
    "mezzanine.forms",
    "mezzanine.accounts",
    "mezzanine.mobile",
)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (    
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.UpdateCacheMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.request.CurrentRequestMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForDeviceMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForHostMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.AdminLoginInterfaceSelectorMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.SitePermissionMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.pages.middleware.PageMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.FetchFromCacheMiddleware",
)
```

In my `index.html`:

```
{% ifinstalled mezzanine.mobile %}
  <span class="separator">|</span>
  <a href="{% url "set_device" "mobile" %}?next={{ request.path }}">{% trans "View Mobile Site" %}</a>
  {% endifinstalled %}
```

But I get this error when I access my `index.html`:

```
Reverse for 'set_device' with arguments '('mobile',)'
  and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this exception?

Answer (score 0):

The exception means that django couldn't find a match in it's urls configuration.

Did you add some in the root `urls.py`? Post the file.

Maybe you are missing to include in it something like this:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'the_app_name/', include('the_app_name.urls')),
    ...
]
```

So, you should have an url somewhere named `set_device` that accepts *'mobile'* as parameter, something like this

```
app_name = 'the_app_name'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^my_url/(?P<type>(mobile|...))/$', my_view, name='set_device'),
...
```

Should we asume it's built in the CMS or is it your own?

Comment: It was supposed to be built in the mezzanine.

Comment: You've helped me to realize the mezzanine version that I'm using (**4.3.0**) no longer has the mobile option. Thanks @guillermo-chamorro